# virtual hosts are linked to internal address

Tags: linux, virtualhost

I am trying to transfere my website in my new server.
I have an internal adresse.ex: xxx-wwwyyy.net
`www.site1.com` : production web site 
`www.site2.com` : preproduction web site

In my site-available folder I created some vhost files:`www.site1.com` and `www.site2.com`

The problem is that both of them are linked to **`xxx-wwwyyy.net`**:

If I create a vhost for `xxx-wwwyyy.net` and i give it my site folder adress: 
`/var/www/site/prod` , 
then my `**www.site1.com**`  and `**www.site2.com**` go to the same adresse.

If I delete `xxx-wwwyyy.net` , all of them go to `/var/www/`

I am just confuised. has anyone any idea?

Answer (score 0):

hello you are trying to create name-based virtual hosts.. make sure NameVirtualHOst *:80 is uncommented in your httpd.conf  ... have a look in here:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.domain.tld
ServerAlias domain.tld *.domain.tld
DocumentRoot /www/domain
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.otherdomain.tld
DocumentRoot /www/otherdomain
</VirtualHost>
```